# How does one interpret $\cup_{X\epsilon \mathscr{C}}X'$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading through Section 5 of Paul Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*, and I've hit some odd notation that I could use a little help in reading.

We begin by defining the power set of some set $E = \{a,b\}$ as $$\mathscr{P}(E)=\{\varnothing, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$$

and we let $\mathscr{C}$ be a subset of $\mathscr{P}(E)$, say let $$\mathscr{C} = \{\{a\},\{b\}\}$$

and $$\mathscr{D}=\{X\epsilon\mathscr{P}(E):X'\epsilon\mathscr{C}\}$$

which I take to mean that (given $\mathscr{C}$ as defined above) $\mathscr{D}=\{\varnothing,\{a,b\}\}$.

Assuming that's correct, could we not simply define $\mathscr{D}$ as $\mathscr{P}(E)-\mathscr{C}$ or $\mathscr{P}(E)\cap\mathscr{C}'$ ?

Further, Halmos says that the custom when denoting the union of the sets in the collection $\mathscr{D}$ by $\cup_{X\epsilon \mathscr{C}}X'$, and the intersection of the sets in the collection $\mathscr{D}$ by $\cap_{X\epsilon \mathscr{C}}X'$.

Assuming I understand how to read the definition of $\mathscr{D}$, what's the best way to read $_{X\epsilon\mathscr{C}}X'$?

Comment: Do you mean how you would _pronounce_ the formula if you had to read it aloud to someone over the phone?

Comment: No, I'm mean how does one interpret the collection of symbols in this particular context

Comment: It looks strange to me. Is there a definition of what the prime means? I know what $X'$ might mean if $X$ is a subset of a topological space, but not if $X$ is just some set, _period_.

Comment: I agree, it does look very strange indeed. Halmos uses prime as a logical negation.  For example, $X'$ would be the set of everything except those members of $X$.